# Json response data extraction using linux command

Tags: json, linux, shell, jq

Below is the json response of an api endpoint, I wanted to get the id value of specific name in the below array of json response.

```json
{
  "self": "https://testtoo.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/project/TEST/version?maxResults=50&startAt=0",
  "maxResults": 50,
  "startAt": 0,
  "total": 2,
  "isLast": true,
  "values": [
    {
      "self": "https://testtoo.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/version/10001",
      "id": "10001",
      "description": "test release",
      "name": "test2",
      "archived": false,
      "released": true,
      "releaseDate": "2021-12-29",
      "userReleaseDate": "29/Dec/21",
      "projectId": 10000
    },
    {
      "self": "https://testtoo.atlassian.net/rest/api/3/version/10002",
      "id": "10002",
      "name": "test3",
      "archived": false,
      "released": true,
      "projectId": 10000
    }
  ]
}
```

eg: I wanted to get id value(10002) of name test3, with the help of name key. Using jq I'm able to select the name key, but I'm not to find a way to get previous key value(id) using name key! My requirement is to get id value by inputting the corresponding name value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```sh
jq -r --arg name "test3" '.values[] | select(.name== $name).id'
```

```
10002
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/VS3d1W0vlx)

Comment: I had simplified it even more to

 jq -r '.values[] | select(.name=="'"$name"'").id

Comment: @vikramanarut In my opinion, this is no simplification. Your version is just a few characters shorter, less readable due due cluttered quoting, and most importantly more vulnerable to [code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection). If your variable contained a `"`  character, jq would interpret it as string boundary and continue interpreting what followed as variable content. WIth some elaboration, one could introduce even malicious behaviour to your script. Using `--arg`, no variable content can slip into execution.